# How do I display active/recent users on my homepage.. but in a server friendly way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I know I can do this using a "for" or "each" loop and limit the results to like 20 recent users but what data would be best to use for determining how a user is recognised as recent/active?

Maybe every time a user sends a message update an updated_at column some where?
Every time a user logs in update the session or something?

Not quite sure what the best way to do this is.. Maybe update the updated_at column in the users table when the send a message, leave a comment.. not too sure what the best way to do this will be.

Having users images on the home page in small boxes will look nice with my design but I don't know how this will impact my server once I launch.

I remember twitter done this then a little while later removed this feature from their homepage.

Anyway thanks in advance.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `:touch => true`([documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Timestamp/touch)). Its a good way to do this, I think.

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :touch => true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A consistent  way is to update a lastseen (timestamp) colum (user talbe) on login. When the session timesout you update again.  With a sort "lastseen desc" and a limit you can make easy a recent list.

Comment: But what about when a user uses "remember me" checkbox..preventing the session from timing out until they log out.

Answer (score 0):

In your `ApplicationController` create an empty session.

When a user logged in, save the user_id and the time as lasttimeseen inside the session created previously, using a Hash.

Create a before_filter in your `ApplicationController` to ensure that the lastimeseen be updated.

The idea is to have a unique session containing all the logged in users and time of last action performed.

Once you have this, you can fetch the last 20 most recent users.